# Using where clause in ClusterFeatureLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, clustering

I am using the ClusterFeatureLayer ([cluster-layer-js](https://github.com/Esri/cluster-layer-js)) and I am trying to use where clause. It works fine when I use it in initial request something like this:

```
clusterLayer = new ClusterFeatureLayer({
        "url": featureServiceCoinFindings,
        "distance": 95,
        "id": "clusters",
        "labelColor": "#fff",
        "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,
        "singleTemplate": false,
        "disablePopup": true,
        "singleSymbol": defaultSym,
        "useDefaultSymbol": false,
        "zoomOnClick": true,
        "showSingles": true,
        "objectIdField": "OID",
        "where": "ID < 50",
        outFields: ["*"]
    });
```

But I want initially to load all features and then on button search to filter some of them. When I do something like this `clusterLayer.where = "ID < 50";` on button click, the clusterLayer doesn't refresh and I still have all features shown in clusters on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not directly filter data like this. You need to reload cluster with your where condition similar to what you are doing initially.